# When $\operatorname{Hom}_{R}(M,N)$ is finitely generated as $\mathbb Z$-module or $R$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Assume that $M$ and $N$ are two finitely generated $R$-modules. Then $\operatorname{Hom}_{R}(M,N)$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb Z$-module and/or $R$-module (in this case, assume that $R$ is commutative)?

Note that $R$ is not Noetherian ring. Is there any counterexample (for any cases)?

Comment: $M = N = R = \mathbb{Q}[x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots]$ has $\textrm{Hom}_R(M, N) = R$, which is certainly not a f.g. $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Comment: How can i prove $Hom_{R}(M,N)=R$?

Comment: @Ali, you would have better chance if you replace $\mathbb Z$ by $R$ and add finite presentation hypothesis.

Comment: @QiL, Please explain..

Comment: I think he means sth like: if $M$ and $N$ are finitely *presented* $R$-modules, then hopefully $Hom_R(M,N)$ is also a finitely presented/generated $R$-module.

Comment: @Ali, $\text{Hom}_R(R,N)$ is isomorphic to $N$ (prove this!). Then, if you take $N=R$ you get that $\text{Hom}_R(R,R)$ is isomorphic to $R$, so no chance (in general) to be finitely generated ovez $\mathbb{Z}$. (Take, for example, $R=\mathbb{Q}$.)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8996/hom-of-finitely-generated-modules-over-a-noetherian-ring could help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $R$ is not noetherian it is not clear (to me) what kind of finiteness conditions on modules would imply that $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N)$ is finitely generated. Even for finitely presented modules this property fails. An example is the following: $R=K[X_1,\dots,X_n,\dots]/(X_1,\dots,X_n,\dots)^2$, $M=R/I$, where $I=(x_1)$, and $N=R$.

However, there are some trivial cases when $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N)$ is finitely generated, e.g. $M$ finitely generated and projective and $N$ finitely generated.

Comment: If $M$ is finitely-generated and $N$ is noetherian, then $\textrm{Hom}_R (M, N)$ is also finitely-generated (indeed, noetherian).

Comment: How can we see that Hom(M,N) is not finitely generated in this example?

Comment: $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R/I,R)\simeq (0:_RI)=(x_1,\dots,x_n,\dots)$.