# Do finitely generated modules have finitely generated endomorphism modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, finitely-generated

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Let $M$ be an $R-$module generated by $m_1, \ldots, m_n$. Is $\textrm{End}_R(M)$ a finitely generated $R-$module?

My own attempt at proving this used the endomorphisms

$$ f_{i,j}: f_{i,j}(m_i) = m_j, f_{i,j}(m_k) = 0 (k \neq i),$$

of which I am not sure they are well-defined.

EDIT: Those generating endomorphisms are in general *not* well-defined; can we impose a condition on  $m_1, \ldots, m_n$ so that they are? In a vector space, demanding  $m_1, \ldots, m_n$ to be linearly independent would be sufficient.

Comment: For the parenthetical questions, consider the case where $M=\{m_1,\ldots,m_n\}$.

Comment: I've also figured out that those generating endomorphisms are *not* well-defined, in particular for $m_i = m_j$. There needs to be some condition similar to linear independence (but I'm not sure we can enforce this in a module...). I do not understand your comment though, @KeithKearnes

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof He means when we take $M = R$, which is to say that we consider $R$ as an $R$ module.  In any case, there is indeed a problem whenever the $m_i$ have non-trivial relations.

Comment: I believe that this is equivalent to the statement that the dual module $\operatorname{Hom}(M,R)$ is finitely generated if $M$ is finitely generated. To that end, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/392620/81360).  I think that the answer to your question is no.

Comment: All right, thank you both. I am actually trying to prove that $M$ is Noetherian implies that $R \setminus \textrm{Ann}_R M$ is Noetherian, and it seems I'll have to try another approach, as my first attempt hinged on the property in title.

Comment: A counterexample for $Hom(M,N)$ yields a counterexample $End(M\oplus N)$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde somewhat of a disappointment to see that 2 years after finishing my Master's, none of these terms mean anything to me anymore :)