# Does $M$ finitely presented and $N$ finitely generated imply Hom$_R(M,N)$ f.g. when $R$ is not Noetherian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

> If $R$ is a non-Noetherian ring, $M$ is a finitely presented $R$-module, and $N$ is a finitely generated $R$-module, does it hold that Hom$_R(M,N)$ is a finitely generated $R$-module?

We tried applying the Hom$(-,N)$ functor to the sequence $R^n \rightarrow R^m \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0$ and using the fact that $N$ f.g. implies Hom$(R^m,N)$ are f.g., but we have no clue how to proceed.

Comment: I don't think what you ask for is true. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234485/when-operatornamehom-rm-n-is-finitely-generated-as-mathbb-z-module-o/239564#239564)

Comment: That seems promising, though it's not clear to me that the Hom is necessarily not finitely generated in that example. Can you explain why that may be?