# Finitely generated modules

Tags: modules, homological-algebra

Suppose that $R$ is a commutative ring and $M$ and $N$ are finitely generated $R-$modules.
What we can say about $Hom_R (M,N)$? is it a finitely generated $R$-module?

Comment: Maybe see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8996/hom-of-finitely-generated-modules-over-a-noetherian-ring

Comment: So If  $R$ is a commutative noetherian ring, then $Hom (M,N)$ is finitely generated. but if $R$ is not noetherian, is $Hom (M,N)$ finitely generated?

Comment: It is already not necessarily the case that the dual of a finitely generated module is finitely generated: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392620/is-the-dual-of-a-finitely-generated-module-finitely-generated .

Answer (score 0):

As [said by a previous user of Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/239564/8348) (user now deleted):

> If $R$ is not noetherian it is not clear (to me) what kind of finiteness conditions on modules would imply that $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N)$ is finitely generated. Even for finitely presented modules this property fails. An example is the following: $R=K[X_1,\dots,X_n,\dots]/(X_1,\dots,X_n,\dots)^2$, $M=R/I$, where $I=(x_1)$, and $N=R$.
>
> However, there are some trivial cases when $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N)$ is finitely generated, e.g. $M$ finitely generated and projective and $N$ finitely generated.

Comment: If you are going to entirely copy another user's answer, you should at the very least make it clear that the work is not your own.

Comment: Hi there, intended to do that but deleted part of it that wasn't relevant. I deleted the comment I wrote about it being somebody else's answer, I perhaps should've just posted a link to the other question. Many thanks.